# How to Transform tf::Transform to btTransform

Tags: c++, ros, bulletphysics

```
void broadcastKinectTransform(const tf::Transform& transform,
                              const std::string& kinect_rgb_optical,
                              const std::string& ground,
                              tf::TransformBroadcaster& broadcaster,
                              const tf::TransformListener& listener) {
    std::string link;
    if (listener.getParent(kinect_rgb_optical, ros::Time(0), link) && listener.getParent(link, ros::Time(0), link)) {
        tf::StampedTransform tfTransform;
        listener.lookupTransform (link, kinect_rgb_optical, ros::Time(0), tfTransform);
        broadcaster.sendTransform(tf::StampedTransform(transform * tfTransform.asBt().inverse(), ros::Time::now(), ground, link));
    } else {
        broadcaster.sendTransform(tf::StampedTransform(transform, ros::Time::now(), ground, kinect_rgb_optical));
    }
}
```

In the above function `.asBt()` is deprecated, what should I do to finish the transformation? How to convert `tf::Transform` to `btTransform` and vice versa ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`tf::Transform` is another name for `btTransform`.

Have a look to its definition in [tf/transform_datatypes.h](http://docs.ros.org/diamondback/api/tf/html/c++/transform__datatypes_8h.html): `typedef btTransform tf::Transform`.

You can simply use the `tf::Transform::inverse()` method. Have a look at the [tf::Transform documentation](http://docs.ros.org/jade/api/tf/html/c++/classtf_1_1Transform.html).